# How to determine if an argument to a function is different from the last invocation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function `x` taking one parameter `y`. Inside `x`, I want to determine if `y` is the same or different from the previous call to `x` (actually it is only part of `y` I care about, but the splitting details are not relevant).

Currently, I use a global `last_y` initialized with an impossible `y` value and check `y` != `last_y`.

I'm curious if there is any clean (non global) way to do this? I was hoping using `nonlocal` would work, but one of my targets is Python 2.7.

Is there a non-`global` solution for all Python versions?

```py
last_y="" # only used by x
def x(y):
    if y != last_y:
        #<do something>
       last_y = y
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2.7, then I think using `getattr` and `setattr` would be the best approach:

```
def f(y):
    if getattr(f, 'old_y', None) != y:
        print('New y is not equal to old y!')

    else:
        print('New y is equal to old y!')

    setattr(f, 'old_y', y)

f('same')
f('same')
f('different')
```

Output:

```
New y is not equal to old y!
New y is equal to old y!
New y is not equal to old y!
```

Comment: `getattr` and `setattr` work in 2.x and 3.x, so you should be fine even without the "2.7" qualifier. I'd suggest passing a default to the `getattr` call, though, so you don't have to do a `setattr` outside the function.

Comment: @CraigMeier Regarding default for `getattr`: I actually didn't know that was possible, thanks! About your first point, what I meant was more "if you want an approach that works for *both*, as opposed to *just* Python 3", since I had some ideas that I'm not sure would work on 2.7.

Comment: `f.old_y = y` does the same thing as `setattr`, with initialization you could also replace the `getattr` with `if f.old_y != y:`

Comment: Perfect -- just what I was looking for.  The default value for getattr works perfectly too to keep the code succinct.  Thanks.  I will go with setattr instead of assignment, because it is consistent with getattr and should make it clearer to any reader.

Comment: @StevenDeller You can, in general, click on the tick to accept an answer, which will signify that it has solved the specific problem you raised in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy your old variable. Use copy module and try something like this

```py
def x(y):
    last_y="" 
    if y != last_y:
       last_y = copy.deepcopy(y)
```